# Leverage sudo access for simpler rsync?

Tags: ssh, sudo, rsync

I have SSH access to a server as a non-privileged user.  I have sudo access on the server that allows me to `su` to `root`.

I need to pull some files from the server.  The files are only readable by `root`.

One way to do this (without annoying UI solutions, just command line only, please) is to log in remotely, use `sudo` to copy the file to my non-privileged user's home directory, give the copy of the file read access for my non-privileged account, exit the remote shell, then use `rsync` to pull the copy of the file across the network.

This is really annoying.  Is there a simpler way to leverage `sudo` access to pull these files across the network?

---

(I am authorized to pull the files but by company policy I may not log in as `root` directly over the network as it prevents accountability—there is no record of who logged in that way.  So I can't add my SSH key to the `authorized_keys` file.)

Comment: You could add a group, add your unprivileged user to said group, then make the file readable by the group. That way, it will only be readable by you and root.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen, it's in `root`'s home directory, so that won't work in this case.  More to the point, assume for this question that I am not authorized to edit the file in any way, including `chmod`—only to make a copy of it (whether locally or across the network).  The "yes/no" version of the question is: Can I *pull* (not push) this file across the network without first making a local copy of it on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can sudo on the remote without needing a password you can simply add to an ordinary rsync the option `--rsync-path=`*remote command*, eg

```
rsync -av --rsync-path='sudo rsync' me@remote:/root/ ~/rootcopy/
```